# Save `buildTime` and `hash` of react build when using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack to build my react project and I want to get `buildTime` and `hash` of the build and save in a json file.

I tried it using `getStats` method of `compilation` object using compiler hooks but I couldn't succeed. So, What's a better way of doing this? I do not want to use any third party plugins, neither using npm script. It has to be done exclusively from the webpack config file.

Comment: What would the hash be a hash of?